# How to get the number of rows if you have both 1D and 2D arrays?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two arrays as follows and would like to get the number of rows by function `.shape`.

```
X = np.array([0, 4, 3, 5, 1, 2])

Y = np.array([[-1, 0, 4, 4],
              [ 1, 0, 5, 0],
              [ 2, 7, 4, 0],
              [ 3, 0, 4, 9],
              [ 4, 6, 4, 0]])

X.shape[0]
Y.shape[0]
```

The result is

```
6
5
```

Because `X` is a matrix with 1 row, I expect `X.shape[0]` returns `1`. However, it returns `6` which is the number of columns. Could you please suggest a function to achieve my goal?

Comment: You might want to try out `np.atleast_2d`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Divakar! It works perfectly fine.

Comment: Look at `.shape`, without the [0]. One is (6,), the other (5,4). `X` doesn't have rows/columns, just 'elements'.  Actually though 'rows' is an informal term that isn't used much in `numpy`.

Comment: With `atleast_2d` the array is no longer 1d.

Comment: I understand your point @hpaulj, but `atleast_2d` helps me achieve my goal :)

Comment: You might find its code instructive.  Essentially it does `if arr.ndim==1: return arr[None,:]`.  It just adds a dimension conditionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Divakar's comment, the command to achieve this goal is `np.atleast_2d`.